# Does Google Nearby Connections 2.0 support development on an emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-nearby

I've been trying to get an example working on a few emulated devices, and it hasn't been easy: Bluetooth isn't supported on emulators, so I thought it would [auto-fall-back to WiFi, or even supersonic communication](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/announcing-nearby-connections-20-fully.html)?  But even after getting permissions working (yay), it dies with the following.

```
E/NearbyConnections: Failed startAdvertising(1, 4, 0, 5, 5, 8) for client 102877343 because we couldn't start listening for incoming Bluetooth connections to ServiceId MYID
W/MeshConnection: Advertising failed. Received status 8007 STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR
E/NearbyConnections: Failed startDiscovery() for client 102877343 because we couldn't scan on Bluetooth nor BLE for serviceId MYID
W/MeshConnection: Discovering failed. Received status 8007 STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some asking around, and it turns out that Nearby Connections 2.0 uses bluetooth to make the connection, then opportunistically upgrades to WiFi if available, so it does need BT to kick things off -- so no running it on emulators.